# Maximum of a subharmonic function on it's boundary.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, potential-theory

I am trying to solve below problem of the book Partial Differential Equations(Third edition) written by jurgen just, problem 3.9. Can any one give an idea? Thanks in advance.

Let $\Bbb R^2:=\{(x_1,x_2)\}$, $\Omega$:=$B^{\circ}(0,R_2)$$\setminus$$B(0,R_1)$ with $R_2$$>$$R_1$$>$0. The function $\phi:= a + b \log(|x|)$ is harmonic in $\Omega$ for all a,b. Let u$\in$$C^2$($\Omega$)$\cap$$C^0(\bar{\Omega})$ be subharmonic, i.e.,
                          $\hspace{7.2cm}\Delta$u$\geq$0, $\hspace{0.6cm}$     $x$$\in$$\Omega$.

Show that

$\hspace{6cm}$M(r)$\leq$${M(R_1)\log({R_2\over r}) + M(R_2)\log({r\over R_1})}\over{\log({R_2\over R_1})}$

with $$M(r):=\max_{\partial B(0,r)} u(x)$$
and $R_1$$\leq$r$\leq$$R_2$.

Comment: Are you sure $M$ is the maximum on the circle with radius $R_2$ (rather that $r$)? If yes, what is it's depency on $r$?

Comment: You was right. it was r(rather than $R_2$).

Answer (score 1):

Since you're given a hint in the form of function $\phi$, it's natural to relate it to the stated inequality. To this end, define
$$ \phi(x) = {{M(R_1)\log({R_2\over |x|}) + M(R_2)\log({|x|\over R_1})}\over{\log({R_2\over R_1})}}$$
which is a harmonic function. Observe that $\phi(x)=M(R_k)$ when $|x|=R_k$, for $k=1,2$. Thus, $u - \phi\le 0$ on the boundary. By the maximum principle, $u-\phi\le 0$ in the domain, which was to be proved.

---

*Remark*. This inequality, often known as the 3-circle lemma, expresses the fact that $M(r)$ is a convex function of $\log r$. Convex functions are distinguished by the property "graph lies below secant". Similarly, subharmonic functions "lie below harmonic". In this setting, $\phi$ is a harmonic function that plays the role of the secant.